# Spring package swap

Tags: java, spring, package

I am quite new to Spring framework. I have problem and I even don't know where to start.
I'll give you an example what I want to do.
Suppose I have those packages

```
com.version.v1
com.version.v1_3
com.version.v2
com.restofapplication...
```

All versions packages are a copy of one module with slight changes. Is it possible to configure spring in a some way, to just tell it in applicationContext.xml to use for example v1_3 and it do the rest (compile aplication using v1_3 package)?

And further question, but package status first:
Lets say that v1 is basic version and contains

```
SomeInterface.java
SomeInterfaceImpl.java
SomeDependentClass.java
```

and v1_3 looks like:

```
SomeInterfaceImpl.java
SomeDependentClass.java
```

So after answering first question, will it be possible to avoid full package copying and make spring to take only changed files from requested version and scan for missing files in lower version?

Can you answer me is it possible at all? Give some clues? Point directions?
Thank you for reading it anyway.

OK, so lets give more information.
I know that I should use tool like GIT to do this, but my intentions are different.
Git is for code versioning.

Here it is what I am asking you for.

I have a webservice with one endpoint, and this endpoint is created in v1 package.
So lets say that I need to modify this endpoint so I create v2 package, by copying v1 and modyfing it.
But I need to have both versions ready to run or run simultaneously, so this is not typical GIT usage.

What I asked in first question is this, is this: Is it possible to select during compilation process which version will be activated? Now I understand that this is Maven task rather than Spring, but is this possible?

And second question. I said that I created V2 on base V1 with modification. But lets say that only one file was modified. So is there a way to copy only that one file to V2 and tell Spring/maven to collect missing files from V1?

Comment: Did someone give you the impression that this was what Spring is for?  Seems like an odd request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not job for Spring. You should use a SCM system like `CVS`, `SVN`, `Git` or something else.  Here is full list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software

In case you must have the different versions in your project then I suggest a *smart* build system(for ex. build with `Ant` or `Maven`), but this will be much more expensive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create contexts for each possible use-case and import them in root context depending on your needs, however you'll need to deliver all of your packages.  like this

```
<import resource="services.xml"/>
<import resource="resources/messageSource.xml"/>
<import resource="/resources/themeSource.xml"/>

<bean id="bean1" class="..."/>
<bean id="bean2" class="..."/>
```

But in order to differentiate deliveries you'll have to make three different builds, and use (or not use)  any configuration tool like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use SCM for this, but if you must.

You can set up the context component scan with Spring 3.1 via code.  It will be up to you to implement the filters for your rules above.

See the java doc for ComponentScan
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

If you cannot get ComponentScan to work, you will also want to look at the AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, extend it, and call into the register and scan from your constructor.  Like this:

```
public class CustomContext extends AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext {
    public CustomContext() {
        super();
        this.scan("com.version.v2");
        this.register(com.version.v1.SomeInterface.class);
    }
}
```